# regex to accept only numbers, hypens, plus sign and space

Tags: c#, regex

I need to create an regex that accepts only numbers, hypens (`-`), plus sign (`+`), spaces along with round brackets `(` `)`.

I tried the regex `(?\+?\d+)?[-.\s]?\d+[-.\s]?\d+`.

What is need is like `(123) 123-123-123`, `(+91) 123-123-1234` or `1234567890`, or `123 123 1234` or `+92 345 345 3456` or `+92 123-123-1234`.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: yes I tried alot, but couldnt make it a fix

Comment: Can you share what you have tried and provide some sample data with the expected results?

Comment: I tried this one \(?\+?\d+\)?[-.\s]?\d+[-.\s]?\d+ and i need to be able to put as many as spaces, plus signs, hypens, round brackets in the texbox

Comment: Can you add that to your question with some sample data?

Comment: Something like this? https://regex101.com/r/zrPxVE/3/

Comment: @SunilThakur Please don’t put the most relevant details in comments. Instead [edit] your question next time. Please check whether the updated question is what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex starts with `(?\+?\d+)?` which is not correct. Maybe you were looking for [`(?:\+?\d+)?[-.\s]?\d+[-.\s]?\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/MTmFUh/1/) which makes the first group non capturing.

If you want to match only numbers, hyphens (-), plus sign (+), spaces along with round brackets ( ) one or more times (so `++++` would also match) you could use:

[`^[-+\d() ]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/BLgwBC/1)

If you want to narrow down your match for your provided strings maybe this could be an option.

There are 2 parts:

1. The optional part at the beginning `(123)` or `(+91)` or `+92`
2. A whitespace followed by either a format like `123-123-123` with hyphens or without hyphens `123 123 1234`

[`^(?:\+\d+|\(\+?\d+\))?(?:\d{10}| ?\d{3}([ -])\d{3}\1\d{3,4})$`](https://regex101.com/r/IWDc4l/1)

**Explanation**

- From the beginning of the string `^`
- A non capturing group `(?:`
- Which matches either a plus sign and one or more digits `\+\d+`
- Or `|`
- Match parenthesis with an optional plus sign, one or more digits and parenthesis `\(\+?\d+\)`
- Close the non capturing group and make it optional `)?`
- A non capturing group `(?:`
- Which matches either 10 digits `\d+{10}`
- Or `|`
- Optional whitespace and digits pattern `?\d{3}([ -])\d{3}\1\d{3,4}` which uses a capturing group `\1` for the whitespace or the hyphen.
- Close the non capturing group `)`
- The end of the string `$`